# Connect VS 2008 to My remote IIS 7 site

Tags: asp.net, windows

I am trying to connect Via 2008 to a remote IIS 7 site on windows server 2008.  I have installed the front page ext on my server and assigned users/roles to my various sites. When I try and connect via vs 2008 it prompts me for user name and password but will not connect.  It seems like a simple issue but I cannot figure it out.  What authentication modes must be enable on IIS.  Anyone have any sugestions

I am not running ftp on the server in question.  When the drive was shared VS could access the directory fine. IIS is running windows authenication mode.

Comment: what authentication mode do you have setup? For the fact that its prompting you for password eliminates the firewall. It might be worth starting up your vs 2008 in administrative mode i.e right-clicking the Visual Studio 2008 icon in the Start Menu and choosing Run as administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the VS2008 user has windows permission to access the target folder(s).
2. Make sure the firewall (windows and external, if there is one) has the proper ports open.
3. If VS2008 is using FTP, try active instead of passive. If that makes a difference, there are some special things you can do to make passive FTP work.
4. Make sure IIS is set up properly for ftp and/or front page extensions, application pools, etc.